# Tab completion for ejs tags such as <% %>

Tags: visual-studio-code, ejs, tab-completion

I am using ejs for my template engine. In the .ejs files, it is fine to tab completion with normal html tags. However, I cannot find a way to tab completion for ejs tags such as <% %>``<%= %> etc. How could I make it?